Pieri's formula over general rings
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Pieri's formula gives an isomorphism
$S^{\lambda}V \otimes \Lambda^{m}V \cong \bigoplus_{\lambda(m)}S^{\lambda(m)}V$,
where $S^{\lambda}V$ is the Schur functor corresponding to Young diagram $\lambda$ and we take the sum over all Young diagrams $\lambda(m)$ obtained from $\lambda$ by adjoining $m$ boxes, no two of which are in the same row. There is a similar statement for $Sym^{m}$, and both isomorphisms are special cases of the Littlewood–Richardson rule.
I have only seen this isomorphism proven in the context of $\mathbb{C}$, for example in Fulton-Harris Representation theory and in Fulton's Young Tableaux.
My question is to what generality of rings does this isomorphism continue to hold?
My guess is that Pieri's formula continues to hold over fields of characteristic zero (the same proof for $\mathbb{C}$ should work I guess), but for arbitrary commutative rings, I am not so sure.
If anyone can point me to some references, that would be much appreciated.

There is a Littlewood-Richardson rule for free modules over arbitrary commutative rings, but it is not a direct sum decomposition. Instead it says "there is a filtration of $S^\lambda\left(V\right) \otimes S^\mu\left(V\right)$ whose subquotients are isomorphic to $S^\nu\left(V\right)$, where each $\nu$ appears $c^{\nu}_{\lambda,\mu}$ times". Here $V$ is a free module, and the $S$ stands for one of the versions of Schur functors. See Giandomenico Boffi, The universal form of the Littlewood-Richardson rule, Advances in Mathematics, 1988.

Also Boffi's thesis should be relevant (available on libgen as well).

A direct sum decomposition is too much to ask (unless $n!$ is invertible in the base ring, probably). Even $V \otimes V$ does not break into $S^{\left(2\right)}\left(V\right) \oplus S^{\left(1,1\right)}\left(V\right)$ if the base ring is $\mathbb F_2$, unless I'm mistaken.

@darijgrinberg Ah nice, thanks for the references. To be honest, I'm only interested in the case where we are working over a field of characteristic zero, so it is reassuring to know you also think the direct sum decomposition should hold in this case. Of course, I  still need to prove the result.....

The case of an arbitrary field of characteristic $0$ can be done in the same way as the case of $\mathbb{C}$: Each polynomial representation of $\operatorname{GL}\left(V\right)$ has a character, which is a symmetric polynomial, and the tensor product corresponds to the product of characters. The main downside of this approach is that it doesn't give you the explicit direct addends (but in the case of the Pieri rule, this is okay, since the sum is multiplicity-free, so you can use isotypic projectors to isolate them).

@darijgrinberg Awesome. I will need some time to digest your argument, but thank you for taking the time to think about this.
